# NSIS Prevent unziping of file to extraction.

Tags: nsis

I have seen this was asked in the bask back in 2008 and can't find anything newer on the subject so I am bring it up again.

Is there a way to prevent a user from extracting the files from the installer and reading the nsi file.

I read something the opcode needs to be changed in the exe of nsis. Has NSIS come up with a plugin or something so users do not have to modify the exe?

If there an easy way or is it still messing with the exe. and if so can you point me in the right direction on how to do this or if someone has already posted a version

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS is open source so it is not unsurprising that people are able to write decompilers.

There is no easy way to prevent it and the recommended method is still the same; change the order of the opcodes in `\Source\exehead\fileform.h` and [compile NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixG.html).

To prevent most people from getting access to your files you can use one of the zip/7z/rar plug-ins from the NSIS Wiki that accepts a password and include a password protected archive in your installer. Keep in mind that a sophisticated user can run the installer in a debugger and find your password when you call the plug-in to extract the files.

Comment: its not so much the files as it is the installer script. I am using blowfish to encrypt data and send it to a server for verification and sending back an encrypt message. I am creating a licence key system for the installer., but that helps. thank you so much for all your help Anders, you have help teach me alot.